# Most efficient way to get JPEG preview of iOS camera - possibly OpenGL

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, core-image, gpuimage

In my app I want to stream the camera preview to another device.  My current approach is to use

```
(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

to get the output and then run that through Apple's sample code that returns a UIImage.  From there I run UIImageJPEGRepresentation() to get my JPEG data.  I'd also like to scale the preview down so that it is just the size of the screen to reduce the image size when streaming.  I've seen approaches use Core Image and GPUImage, but I assume that I will still need to run UIImageJPEGRepresentation() and that will run on the CPU and not the GPU.  I thought of using the preview layer but there is no way to grab its contents.  Again, my goal is to get the preview as a JPG as quickly as possible and scale the image down to the screen size.  Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The best method I've heard hinted of is to record to a mp4 file, while at the same time reading said file and sending any new data stored in it. I'm afraid I can't remember where I found this method described though, and I do not have any sample code :(

Comment: if you have a mp4 container parser I guess you might be able to read the stream, attempt reading at regular intervals, and then send all new frame but the last.